# Python Requests POST timeout prematurely closed connection

Tags: post, python-requests, timeout, nginx-reverse-proxy, connection-close

I'm doing some file uploads that sends to an nginx reverse proxy.  If I set the python `requests timeout` to 10 seconds and upload a large file, nginx will report `client prematurely closed connection` and forward an empty body to the server.  If I remove the requests timeout, the file uploads without any issues.  As I understand it, the timeout should only apply if the client fails to receive or send any bytes, which I don't believe is the case as it's in the middle of uploading the file.  It seems to behave more like a time limit, cutting the connection after 10 seconds with no exception being raised by requests.  Is sending bytes different than reading bytes for timeout?  I haven't set anything for `stream` or tried any type of multi-part.  I would like to set a timeout but confused as to why the connection is getting aborted early - thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you work around this?

Comment: I can't recall if I removed the timeout entirely or set it to something like 10 minutes.  Seems like it shouldn't disconnect if it's sending data, but I never got an explanation or solution.  It wasn't nginx cutting the connection.  It was determined to be the client request post timeout.